# Codeigniter URL rewrite not working with object not found error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am new to codeigniter. I tried to use the url rewrite in my local server to hide index.php folder but it show object not found error when i try to access any controllers. 
or example users/login is not working whereas index.php/users/login is working how to fix it.

**The details are**
application directory -> f:xampp/htdocs/testapp/application/controllers/users

in config.php -> `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

in routes -> `$route['default_controller'] = "users";`

.htaccess rule -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Deny from all
```

working url -

> localhost/bluechip/index.php/users/login

Not working -

> localhost/bluechip/users/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config use

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And use the following .htaccess -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sorry, im a new member hence stack exchange ask for 15 reputations to upvote